# Delete records from one2many in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I need to delete one2many records in onchange method. I have tried below code.

***.py**

```py
@api.onchange('abt')
def _onchange_active(self):
    resident_flat_rel_id =[]
    if self.active == False:
        write=self.write({'resident_flat_rel_ids':[(2,self.resident_flat_rel_ids.id,False)]})
        print'werite', write // prints True.
```

But record doesn't delete from database.

`resident_flat_rel_ids` is one2many field in parent model.

Comment: just one question if the user click on discard after changing this value do you want to cancel the deleted that happend in onchange?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `one2many` is not stored in db. ORM is making `one2many` for you from the related `many2one` fields. Once we know that we can proceed to delete record.

Ok now we know how `one2many` works and we need to remove record. Here is two options: remove record from db or remove only reference from `one2many` field.

For removing record you should delete it (see official documentation for this. hint: unlink()). And if you want to delete just reference then you should erase related record's `many2one` field, simple enough.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing...

If you want to remove complete data do this:

Iterate over your one2many field, ie resident_flat_rel_ids
Like

```py
for individual in resident_flat_rel_ids:
    if some condition: #If it's required
        individual.unlink()
```

If you want to remove only the reference, then do this:
Make the inverse_name (A many2one field which represents a reverse relation for the one2many field) of every object to False

```py
for individual in resident_flat_rel_ids:
    if some condition: #If it's required
        individual.inverse_name = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove one2many records using following one2many rule:
**(2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)**

```
return {'value': {'resident_flat_rel_ids':[(2,individual.id) for individual in self.resident_flat_rel_ids]}}
```